# Convert Date string in NodeIS

Tags: node.js, datetime

I have a TranDate "2017/07/05 12:12:22", i want to convert it to this style : 20170705121222, can you help me what function of nodejs can I use to do this issue ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

There might be built in function in nodeJS, but you can achieve expected output using regex. as below

```
"2017/07/05 12:12:22".match(/\d/g).join('')
```

Comment: Now, This is my way :
       var dateSplit = dateString[0];
        var timeSplit = dateString[1];
        var day = dateSplit.split("/");
        var time = timeSplit.split(":");
        var transactionDate = day[0] + day[1] + day[2] + time[0] + time[1] + time[2];

But I want find more suitable ways( with other cases)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with a replace.

```js
var result = "2017/07/05 12:12:22".replace(/[\/ :]/g, '');
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a module to handle it also:

```
> var df = require('date-format')
> df('yyyyMMddhhmmss', new Date('2017 07 05 12:12:22'))
'20170705121222'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Steve Lacerda (y)

Comment: Can you vote for this post and mark as closed? Thanks and glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

> var df = require('date-format')
>   df('yyyyMMddhhmmss', new Date('2017 07 05 12:12:22'))